# Using the BoundTo Lifestyle in Windsor in conjunction with the TypedFactoryFacility

Tags: castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I would like to use the BoundTo Lifestyle in Windsor in conjunction with the TypedFactoryFacility where the factories maintain their scoped context. However I note that this is currently not supported (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/castle-project-users/txDi3dZ8veQ). Can someone explain how I can achieve this, perhaps there is a different way to do the same thing in Windsor?

I have a scenario similar to the following. In which I am using a Command to add new Panels to a Workspace where I want the same instance of ISomeScopedViewModel to be injected into each Panel I add (created by the factory IWorkspacePanelViewModelFactory).

Scenario:

```
        _container = new WindsorContainer();

        _container.Kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        _container.Register(
           Component.For<IWorkspaceViewModel>().ImplementedBy<WorkspaceViewModel>().LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
           Component.For<ISomeScopedViewModel>().ImplementedBy<SomeScopedViewModel>().LifeStyle.BoundTo<IWorkspaceViewModel>(),
           Component.For<IWorkspacePanelViewModel>().ImplementedBy<WorkspacePanelViewModel>().LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
           Component.For<IWorkspacePanelViewModelFactory>().AsFactory()
        ...
        );
```

Comment: Same question here... did you find an answer?

Comment: I know this is an old question but for any reader you may find your answer in this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/castle-project-users/txDi3dZ8veQ